# Is this hosting question suitable for any Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about whether to self-host a blog (on shared hosting at a reliable provider) vs. using Google's blogging platform in terms of search engine visibility. URL would look the same in both cases.

Is there any Stack Exchange site that this is suitable for?  Which SE site should I ask on?

Comment: Nowhere.  You could try Webmasters chat.

Comment: Maybe you could try [Community Building](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the scarce information you provide it looks like you want to ask the question:

> Should I self-host a blog (on shared hosting at a reliable provider) or should I use Google's blogging platform in terms of search engine visibility? I expect the URL to be the same in both cases.

That question should nowhere be asked in all honesty because it is a [polling or shopping recommendation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and those doesn't fit well in the Q/A format the SE Network uses.

You might assume at first glance that [Webmasters.se](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would take your question because they have the tag and similar questions. The on-topic help page has your type of question explicitly listed as **Off-topic**:

> **Topics with a "catch all" question and answer** -- Many topics are covered by a question with a comprehensive answer. Other questions about the topic are marked as duplicate. Some examples from the list of catch-all questions are:
>
> - [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

The link has advice to help you to answer your own question without the need to actually post it.

If you still feel you need help from users take a step back and rephrase your question so it describes a certain well defined goal. A goal could be: a search ranking better than 60%, a traffic increase of 10%. You can include your current findings, things you tried, etc. I imagine such question will attract answers that bring you closer to the goal you described. Some might suggest tweaking Google webmaster tooling, some might suggest ads, some might suggest a hosting solution.

For help in writing that question consider reading [Smart Questions](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Another option is seeking advice in one of the chat rooms and if fleshed out enough verify on the site-meta if your question is up to par for the main site.

Questions that have that form are interesting for both you and future visitors because it is easier to relate to a goal than it is to a product suggestion that worked for you without knowing your context.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is SEO only, then definitely your question's place belongs to:

> [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

There have 4,883 seo questions [there](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo).

They aslo have 1,075 hosting [questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting); so also if you want to a compare benefits/cost/performance the site will be helpful too.

Comment: Why is this poor answer being downvoted, and without any comments to say why?

Comment: If it's a poor answer, that's one reason for a downvote

Comment: How is that relevant to Yar saying that this is a poor answer? Or are we just attacking for the sake of it?

Comment: Webmaster.se explicitly declare that type of questions off-topic. Be careful if you suggest sites  you are not an active member on. If you do, please add the tip to check their help and meta before posting to prevent the OP has a bad experience.

Comment: Where does it explicitly declare that?

Comment: In the help center